# Radial Visualization coordinate with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to obtain a radial coordinate plot using ggplot2 and the coord_polar(). I have use the drep package from R and obtain a radviz2d(), see [NotMyRadViz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p2mj.jpg). Since I desire to do it in ggplot I extracted all the necessary functions. Also I wish to obtain this using the coord_polar() and when I do it my variables rotate [MyRadViz2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rywK6.jpg). Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
library("dprep")
radviz2d(iris,name="Iris")

#-------------------- Extracted from mmnorm.R
n <- dim(iris)[1]
p <- dim(iris)[2]
classes <- iris[,p]
varnames <- colnames(iris)

dataset <- as.matrix(mmnorm(iris))
dataset <- dataset[,-p]
sumrows <- rowSums(dataset)
columns <- seq(0,p-2)
angles <- (2*pi*columns)
angles <- angles/(p-1)
cosines <- cos(angles)
sines <- sin(angles)
proj.x <- (dataset%*%cosines)
proj.x <- proj.x/sumrows
proj.y <- (dataset%*%sines)
proj.y <- proj.y/sumrows

#--------------- What I'd been doing
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

dataset2 <- melt(dataset/sumrows)
classnumbers <- 1:length(unique(classes))
classes <- as.numeric(classes,drop=TRUE)

Projxy <- data.frame(Projx = proj.x, Projy = proj.y, Ids = classes)
Cos_Sin <- data.frame(Angle = angles,Cos=cosines, 
                                  Sin = sines, Varnames = varnames[-p])
theta <- angles * 180/pi
d2 <- data.frame(theta,Varnames=varnames[-p])

#------------ My ggplot2 
ggplot(data=dataset2,aes(x = Var2, y = value)) + geom_blank() + 
  ylab("") + xlab("") + ggtitle(paste("RadViz 2D for", "Iris")) +
  coord_polar("y",start = pi/2) +
  geom_point(data = Projxy,aes(x = Projx, y = Projy,col = factor(Ids))) +
  coord_polar() + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```